# How to support iOS5 and ios6 maps in same app?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, mapkit

What I should do to support both maps in my app ,I mean that iphone with iOS 5 will see google maps and iOS 6 device will see the new maps

I'll be glad to get a link to a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of the map to load is made by the iOS itself.
You have simply to take care of not using methods added on iOS 6 when you are on iOS 5 (checking if the target responds to selector or using macros to have different code)
The new map support all methods of previous map system. If your project supports iOS 5, you'll see Google Maps when the app is executed on iOS5, and Apple Maps when is executed on iOS6.

A good approach imho, if you are new to iOS programming, is to develop for the iOS 5 target and test on iOS 5 simulator and device. Then, when you move to iOS 6, all should work correctly but on the Apple Maps *automagically* :-)

Answer (score 0):

google have released their own version of Google maps as an SDK

https://developers.google.com/maps/mobile-apps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/